# Nissan Almera 2005 Parking lights and Dash light stop working

Tags: nissan, lights, almera

Nissan Almera 2005 Parking lights and Dash light stopped working. The external fuse box doesn't have a cover to identify the correct fuse.
I need assistance

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Make sure all your fuses physically match this layout first. -->
[image]